# Facebook Application Setting: Site URL Without Trailing slash

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

Is it possible in a Facebook application to set the Site URL to a value *without* a trailing slash? Facebook appears to be doing everything in it's power to ensure Site URL has a trailing slash.

I'm asking because I'm using OmniAuth in a Rails 3 application always strips trailing slashes from the redirect_uri parameter. Thus giving me a "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration." error.

Comment: Earned the Tumbleweed badge for this. Nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I handled this in my app by providing the following in my app/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.full_host = "http://myhost.com" # <- without trailing slash here
```

Dedpending on your production setup, your mileage may vary

Comment: Thanks. This does seem to be the official way to handle this on the OmniAuth side. I think the current gem is a bit behind the most recent code though. At least that was the case a couple of weeks ago. Thanks again.